# Can't use DNS name instead of ip for jdbc connection on local network

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, netplan

I have the following connectionString for my db:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://{someIpAdress}:1433;database=db
```

I want to resolve someIpAdress to the DNS name instead. By running `nslookup` on the ip I get the name for that address. But replacing the Ip with the DNS name results in a failing connection for the jdbc connection.

I have tried modifying the file `/etc/resolv.conf` which now allows me to ping the DNS name, but it seems like the configuration should be done with netplan for `Ubuntu 18.04LTS`. Changes to `interfaces` in `/etc/network` didn't work either.

Some of the guides I've looked at so far: 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-dns-search-list-for-host-name-lookup/

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use 18.04 there is some bug of auto generate resolv.conf file. Create symlink which following command fixs this problem.

```
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

But if you don't have DNS server you can edit `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   com01

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.168.88  lab01
```

From above configuration `com01` is your computer name `192.168.168.88` is your server IP address and `lab01` is your server name.

Hope this help.

Comment: I already have that configuration in `/etc/hosts` and the ln command failed since `/etc/resolv.conf` already exists

Comment: Your answer tunred out to be correct. I had only provided the IP for the parent DNS, but had to manually add thoose i needed

Comment: Just make sure that `resolv.conf` is linked to path  `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` if you use 18.04. It's always not getting right DNS if it isn't linked to the path and you can remove `/etc/resolv.conf` in case it already exist and run command to link file again.